# \Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance() - similar controller in symfony

Tags: symfony, zend-framework

I have a question connected with Symfony. I need to get request, but I don't want just by global variable $_REQUEST. I know, that in Zend is something like Zend_Controller_Front and I can get instance, but I don't know how I can do the same in Symfony. Any ideas? 
Thx.

Comment: If you are talking about the request in controller action you can just type hint it in your action function. Check the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument)

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, it is not request in controller, but I found solution, I think that Request::createFromGlobals() is all what I needed.